# Undefined variable - PHP MYSQL HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a table filled with members list (`listmembers.php`) and one of the column looks like this:

[image]

But, when I click the ban now! or unban now! the page refers to `dobanunban.php` and it shows

**Notice: Undefined variable: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\AM\control\dobanunban.php on line 5**
which refers to `$status = $_REQUEST['status'];`

I have the following code in `listmembers.php`

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include("control/connect.php");

        if(!empty($_SESSION['usernameonline'])){
            if($_SESSION['usernameonline'] == NULL || $_SESSION['usernameonline'] == ""){
                header("location:index.php");
            }
        }
        if(empty($_REQUEST['username'])){
        $username = "";
      }else{
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        }
        $query = NULL;
        $query = "select image,username,fullname,email,phone,status from member where username <> 'admin'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

    ?>


    /----------------------------/

    <td>
    <?php echo $row['status'];?>
    <br/>
    <a id="status" href="control/dobanunban.php?username=<?php 
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['status'];
    ?>">

    <?php   
    if($row['status']=='banned'){
        echo "Unban now!";}
    else{ echo "Ban now!";}
    ?>
    </a>
    </td>
```

And this in my `dobanunban.php`:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $status = $_REQUEST['status'];

    if($status=="unbanned"){
        $query1 = "update  member SET  Status =  'banned' WHERE  username='$username';";
        mysql_query($query1);
        header("location:../listmembers.php?err=Success ban member");
    }else if($status=="banned"){
        $query2 = "update  member SET  Status =  'unbanned' WHERE  username='$username';";
        mysql_query($query2);
        header("location:../listmembers.php?err=Success unban member");
    }
```

Looks like the `$status` didn't get the value from `listmembers.php` echo.
What's my mistake? And what should I do?

Comment: i smell sql injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <a id="status" href="control/dobanunban.php?username=<?php echo $row['username']; ?>

&status=
    //you missed it here

<?php echo $row['status'];?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

you have missed to add status parameter in the URL:

```
<a id="status" href="control/dobanunban.php?username=<?php echo $row['username']; ?>&status=<?php echo $row['status'];?>">
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Sorry I'm still noob at this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify there is two different parameters in your URL, so $_REQUEST['status'] isn't set, thus the Notice.

You should modify this :

```
<a id="status" href="control/dobanunban.php?username=<?php 
echo $row['username'];
echo $row['status'];
?>">
```

To this :

```
<a id="status" href="control/dobanunban.php?username=
<?php echo $row['username'];?>
&status=
<?php echo $row['status'];
?>">
```

EDIT : When using global variables in PHP, like $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $*SESSION, etc, you should check if they are set, with if(isset($*.....)) !

Comment: Thank you! It works. Sorry I'm still noob at this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try like  `&status=<?php echo $row['status'];?>` as in below

```
 id="status" href="control/dobanunban.php?username=<&php  echo $row['username'];?>&status=<&php echo $row['status'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap your $_POST or $_GET values in isset():

```
$status = isset($_REQUEST['status']) ? strip_tags($_REQUEST['status']) : false;

if($status===false){ /* An error occured, status is not defined */ }
```

Also a few handy suggestions:

1. Make sure your code is properly escapes
2. Try to avoid using native mysql_* functions, try mysqli or PDO for database querying.

http://php.net/PDO